# Generating the lexicographically greatest string

Tags: java, string, puzzle

The question is to generate the lexicographically greatest string given some string s.
So the aim is to find lexicographically greatest, unique(no repetitions) substring s1 from s. 
We say that some subsequence s1 is greater than another subsequence s2 if s1 has more characters than s2 or s1 is lexicographically greater than s2 if equal length.

I/O are as follows:

Input is: **ba**bab

output is: ba

Second input is: nlhthgrfdnnlprjtecpdr**t**higjoqdejsfka**soc**tjijaoebql**r**gaiakfsbljm**p**ib**k**id**j**srtk**g**r**d**n**q**sk**nb**arp**a**bgokbsr**fhm**eklr**le**

Second output is: 
tsocrpkijgdqnbafhmle

This is what I wrote for my java code but my code fails on the second test case. Also I'm having a hard time understanding why second output isn't tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba.
Can somebody provide suggestions for a fix or even java code?

I think the algorithm has to be more efficient than generating all possible unique strings, sort them and find lexicographically largest one.

To make the question much clearer, if the input is babab, then all the possible unique combinations would be b, a, ba, ab. And the output will be ba because it's the longest and lexicographically greater than ab.

**Note: this is not a homework assignment.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class mostBeautiful {
final static int MAX = 1000000;
static String[] permute;
static void permutation(String prefix, String str, int counter) {
    int n = str.length();
    //System.out.println("n is: "+ n);
    if (n == 0) {
        permute[counter] = prefix;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //System.out.println("str is: "+ str);
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n), counter++);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = bf.readLine();
    char[] unique = new char[26];
    int counter = 0;
    String answer = "";
    //System.out.println("s is: " + s);
    int ascii = 0;
    final int asciiAVal = 97;
    final int asciiZVal = 122;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        ascii = (int)s.charAt(i);
        if (ascii < asciiAVal || ascii > asciiZVal) {
            continue;
        }
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        unique[ch - 'a'] = ch;
    }
    String result = "";
    for (int j = 25; j >= 0; j--) {
        result += unique[j];
    }
    result = result.trim();
    System.out.println(result);
    int size = result.length() * (result.length() - 1);
    permute = new String[size];
    permutation("", result, counter);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (permute[i].compareTo(permute[i - 1]) > 0){
            answer = permute[i];
        }  else {
            answer = permute[i - 1];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("answer is: " + answer);
}
```

}

Comment: A homework tag is missing, I believe.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but it's not homework. It was one of the questions from the programming contest I failed to solve.

Comment: How is a substring defined here?

Comment: So if the input is babab, then its substring has to consist of distinct characters from the input so a, and b. If the input is nlhthgrfdnnlprjtecpdrthigjoqdejsfkasoctjijaoebqlrgaiakfsbljmpibkidjsrtkgrdnqsknbarpabgokbsrfhmeklrle, then the substring would be any permutations of abcdefghijklmnopqrst.

Comment: It would be more precise to say "subsequence" (can be non-continuous) instead of "substring" (continuous).

Comment: So your true problem statement is to find the set of all chars in the string and sort it in descending order?

Comment: In your comment to @Vovochka's answer below you mention your second test case is valid since it's "the permutation of characters from a to t". But in fact, it's not valid since it's **any** permutation of chars, but because it is a **subsequence**? Above you also say "the substring would be **any** permutations of ...".

Comment: OK what I meant was any permutation of chars or non-continuous subsquence.

Comment: Read my explanation above that starts with, "To make the question much clearer, if the input is babab, ...

Comment: So a descending sort of the set of all chars in a string is **any permutation**. Your example above confirms that: "ba" is the descending-order sort of the set of all chars in "babab".

Comment: the problem description and the output make no sense together. The 2nd output is random chars from the former string.

Comment: The string s1="tsocrpkijgdqnbafhmle" is NOT a substring of the Second input. Please edit your question.

Comment: Second input is: nlhthgrfdnnlprjtecpdrthigjoqdejsfkasoctjijaoebqlrgaiakfsbljmpibkidjsrtkgrdnqsknbarpabgokbsrfhmeklrle

Second output is: tsocrpkijgdqnbafhmle
==> should be:     tsocrispjtgdqnbaofhmkle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this problem in many ways, I have determined a divide-and-conquer algorithm that gets the results right:

#### Algorithm - Pseudocode

Assuming some input string, S defined as a concatenation of two substrings A + B, we compute the lexicographically greatest string recursively as:

```
LexMax(S) = Merge(LexMax(A),LexMax(B))
```

Where

```
LexMax(S)
{
    if Length(S) = 1
        return S
    else
    {
        LMA = LexMax(S[0:Length/2])
        LMB = LexMax(S[Length/2:end])
        return Merge(LMA,LMB)
    }
}

Merge(A,B)
{
    Sa = A
    Sb = B

    for n = 0:Length(A)
    {
        if Sb contains A[n]
        {
            if A[n+1:end] contains character > A[n]
                Remove A[n] from Sa
            else
                Remove A[n] from Sb
        }
    }

    return Sa + Sb
}
```

#### Java Code

Coming soon!

#### Example

Given an input string

```
cefcfdabbcfed
```

Divide it into

```
cefcfda
bbcfed
```

Assuming the function works we have:

```
LexMax("cefcfda") = "efcda"
LexMax("bbcfed") = "bcfed"
```

Merging works as follows:

```
e: efcda bcfed
```

In both substrings, greater value found to right of e in left substring, remove from left

```
f: fcda bcfed
```

In both substrings, no greater value in left substring, remove from right

```
c: fcda bced
```

In both substrings, greater value found to right of c in left substring, remove from left

```
d: fda bced
```

In both substrings, no greater value in left substring, remove from right

```
a: fda bce
```

Not in both substrings, do nothing

Final result:

```
LexMax(cefcfdabbcfed) = fdabce
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the condition in the inner-most if-block is not enough.
Consider merging `cba` and `czba`. Your algorithm will keep `cba` and attach `z` to it, but it should instead remove `ba` from the first part and return `czba`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but doesn't this code meet the requirement as you explained it in the discussion above?

```
final String x = "saontehusanoethusnaoteusnaoetuh";
final SortedSet<Character> chars = 
   new TreeSet<Character>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for (char c : x.toCharArray()) chars.add(c);
System.out.println(chars);
```

Comment: well if you just wrote that code based on my response above it should be correct.

Comment: I did. Quote: "OK what I meant was any permutation of chars or non-continuous subsquence." Me: "So a descending sort of the set of all chars in a string is any permutation. Your example above confirms that: "ba" is the descending-order sort of the set of all chars in "babab"" You: "Marko, that is correct."

Comment: When I said "no it doesn't output lexicographically greatest string," I meant to say that I replaced the variable x with "nlhthgrfdnnlprjtecpdrthigjoqdejsfkasoctjijaoebqlrgaiakfsbljmpibkidjsrtkgrdnqsknbarpabgokbsrfhmeklrle" and compared the output and they didn't match.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that your **real** problem, as deduced indirectly from the clues lying around, is of the NP class.

Comment: haha Marko, this is definitely not NP class problem. Your algorithm is wrong and you seem to be having a hard time understanding a simple English statement. Do you even understand what lexicographical ordering means?

Comment: For the 2nd input and output I also do not understand why the output is not tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba, as suggested by your algorithm as well. But that was pretty much all the explanation given in the problem statement and it's not my fault for ambiguous wording.

Comment: @Marko, I'm here w/ you, from the problem description it appears it just need to sort the unique characters in descending order.

Comment: @bestsss Thanks for helping out :) I in fact think the problem is to find a **subsequence**, meaning you start from top, at each position you decide whether to take that char or not, and go on till the end. That's the classical definition of a subsequence, but OP is consistently failing in making that clear. In fact, he is probably not aware of that meaning. I think his 2nd output is in fact a subsequence satisfying that def, but didn't care to check it.

Comment: OK Marko I did in fact failed to understand that this was to find a subsequence. I blame myself for that. Also I would like to apologize you for anything that might have offended you. But you see I don't get this question. That's why I posted here.

Comment: I remember subsequence like deleting chars from the string. In this case the solution is generating all the longest subsequences containing unique chars and taking the max. Quite trivial indeed.

Comment: @bestsss, would you care to enlighten me how to take the max with some pseudocode?

Comment: @bestsss I think it's non-trivial because you can't know in advance which of the same chars to delete. You can't naively start from top and delete the first repetition---maybe you were not supposed to keep the **first** occurence of that char! For example, "zawyxa" -- see what I mean? That's why I think it's in fact NP.

Comment: I mean, generate **all** *the longest subsequences*. Not just start from the 1st char and keep deleting, if present already. Since the length of the longest possible subsequence is known beforehand (the first generated one will be the longest as it contains all unique chars), some of the subsequences can be cut off earlier. At the moment I can't think of a non-brute force algorithm, though. There could be optimizations like known max. length of unique chars left at any position.

Comment: @bestsss You can easily find **a** subsequence that uses all the chars. Finding **all** such subsequences is already trickier. You have a collection of sets of indices, each set containing the indices of the same char. So you have a set of sets. You need to pick one index from each set, and do that in all possible ways. That seems a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Lexicographic order is an order in which words are displayed in alphabetical order using the appearance of letters in the word.It is also know as dictionary order or alphabetical order.For ex:-"Africa" is smaller than "Bangladesh" ,"He" is smaller than "he".

```
 public class LexicographicExample {  
      public static void main(String a[]) {  
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
           System.out.println("Enter the String:-");  
           String str = sc.nextLine();  
           System.out.println("Enter the length");  
           int count = sc.nextInt();  
           List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
           for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + 1) {  
                if (str.length() - i >= count) {  
                     list.add(str.substring(i, count + i));  
                }  
           }  
           Collections.sort(list);  
           System.out.println("Smallest subString:-" + list.get(0));  
           System.out.println("Largest subString:-" + list.get(list.size() - 1));  
      }  
 }
```

For reference ,refer this link http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2015/09/java-program-to-find-lexicographically.html

Answer (score 0):

"tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba" is not the answer because it is not a subsequence of the input. The definition of subsequence requires that the characters of the subsequence occur in the original sequence *in the same order*. For example, "abc" is a subsequence of "apbqcr", while "cba" is not.

As to the solution, I think a simple greedy algorithm would suffice. First, one has to understand that the maximum possible length of the output is the number of unique symbols (say, N) in the input. Since any output shorter than that would not be the greatest one, it has to be exactly N symbols long. The rest of the procedure is simple and at most quadratic in time complexity: one has to go through the input string and at each step pick the lexicographically highest symbol such that the part of the string to the left of it would still contain all the "unused" symbols.

As an example, consider a string "bacb". The first symbol can be 'a' or 'b', since in both cases the remainder contains both of the other letters. 'b' is greater, so we pick it. Now for "acb" we can only pick 'a' and than 'c' according to that condition, so we end up with "bac" for output.

Answer (score 0):

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        class aaa {
            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                // int n = scan.nextInt();
                String s = scan.next();

                HashMap<Character, Node5> map = new HashMap<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    if (!map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))) {
                        Node5 node = new Node5();
                        node.nl.add(i);
                        node.li = i;
                        map.put(s.charAt(i), node);
                    } else {
                        Node5 rn = map.get(s.charAt(i));
                        rn.nl.add(i);
                        rn.li = i;
                        map.put(s.charAt(i), rn);
                    }
                }

                String s1 = "";
                int index = -1;
                for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (map.containsKey((char) (97 + i))) {
                        if (map.get((char) (97 + i)).li > index) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < map.get((char) (97 + i)).nl.size(); j++) {
                                if (map.get((char) (97 + i)).nl.get(j) > index) {
                                    s1 += (char) (97 + i);
                                    index = map.get((char) (97 + i)).nl.get(j);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(s1);
                scan.close();
            }


        }

        class Node5 {
            int li;
            ArrayList<Integer> nl;

            public Node5() {
                this.nl = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please consider explaining why your code should work - this is important for an old question that already has an accepted answer. You need explain how your answer is adding value.